Moving Harddisk to another computer make files have weird owners

So the owner of the group or usernames is S-15-21-17 bla bla bla....
I can't open the file.
The only way I know how to fix this is to right click one by one and then change ownership one by one.
Selecting multiple file doesn't allow me to access security tab


This is completely normal, since Windows stores these identifiers with files, not the raw usernames (and neither just numbers like Linux).
If both computers are on the same network, you can try to just add permissions for the second computer first by using the form hostname\username on the original computer.
To do this faster, you should be able to take ownership of the while folder, though.
